# Do Americans spend 49 billion dollars a year on pets?

Tags: economics, zoology

I heard that people in Germany spend billions on pets and didn't believe it. But actually Germans spend around 3.3 billion Euro a year. [The source seems serious.](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&u=http://www.wirtschaftswetter.de/ausgabe91/wirtschaftsmachthaustier.html)

The only hint I found for US is [this site](http://www.sandyrobinsonline.com/sandyhtml/Home.html), speaking of a whopping 49 billion US dollars.

This looks exorbitantly high to me when comparing the US population to Germany's, and when considering that Germany is a very pet friendly country. Can someone show a serious source listing e.g. ratio of absolute number and type of animals in US (vs. Germany)? I would really like to know how one can explain this high difference between the two countries and in which fields it arises. Do animals used in US farming contribute to the 49 billion?

---

**on comments:** Im not trying to moralize. This anyway depends on your subjective valueing of 4$/day. I was more suprised by the absolute amount (the **german overall government budget is around 300 billion a year!**) and the relative difference to Germany compared with population ratio (311:80) Most of pet food is very cheap meat waste from production of human food. So (to me) already the 3.3 billion Euro (1% of german government budget) is pretty much. A lot of jobless people in Germany (roughly 1 of 10) would be glad to have additionally $120/month ($1440/year). I don't have to mention people in 3rd world. It would be interesting to know where this **overhead of costs comes from:** too expensive food (profiteering), contributing of animals in farming (I dont think they belong to pet industry) or very expensive vets. There seems also to exist very expensive dogsitting/dog disco (rofl) trends in New York. People having a dog, but paying other to care about (?) :)

Comment: That's approximately $4/day if you count 1 in 10 Americans has a pet (which may be way off, I don't know).

Comment: Maybe more horses in Amerika - see all those cowboys. And horses aren't that cheap.

Comment: And $4 a day isn't much, tbh (on average), especially given the cost of vets (take your dog to the vet twice a year for some vaccinations and a general checkup and you're halfway there already). Need surgery? Vet bill can end up costing you several thousand.

Comment: @user only if you train them to compete with humans on marathons :) I would think main costs for horses for individuals is renting a place in a stabling. But for farmer place cannot be the big cost problem? Probably also vets...

Comment: I can say that we personally spend over 150 a month on our pets. The thing is I make my money and pay my taxes so if I want to spend my money on my pets then it is my money to spend. If they want to make their own money I am not going to judge how they spend it either. The break down is about 90 in food, and 60 in toys/extras. Every 2 months we have one of our dogs groomed professionally so that is an extra 60 on those months. There is a yearly bill of about 200 each for 3 dogs for vet checkup rabies and tags.

Comment: @chad i dont think americans love their pets more than germans. Im just surprised by this relative overhead knowing of the low quality of pet food in Germany but high price. Maybe there is even more profiteering in US pet food industry. Looking on olivers numbers the ratio of population/pets between US/Ger shows some reasons. Cats and dogs exceed the relative population/pet ratio in Germany by far. Maybe because US has much more rural villages where it is often common to have a pet compared to urban places.

Comment: @Hauser - I think you are erroneously equating how much money is spent on pets with how much they are loved. People spend money on their pets based on what they can afford not how much they are loved.  What you call profiteering in germany we call capitolism in the US we definately love that more than you germans do.

Comment: @Chad: high price for low quality is a scam it is not capitalism...

Comment: @Nico - I get a 50 pound bag of dog food for $30 - it feeds my dogs for 2-3 weeks and has pieces of dried chicken.  The dogs love it the quality of their bowels is good and they do not have issues with gas.  There is a reason for buying premium food.  I use the Purina Pro Plus Premium for Small Dogs.  I could get Old Yeller at walmart for ~$7 for 50 lbs but the dogs do not like it and they get gass and runny bowel.

Comment: While there is a lot of high price pet food on the market that isn't particularly high quality, there is also a lot of high quality pet food out there. I'd suggest that "Is all pet food made from low quality waste products?" would be a good separate question, except that I am not aware of any notable sources for that claim.

Comment: @nico: high price for low quality is a scam *called* capitalism...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**YES**, apparently that number is in the correct ballpark.

Accoring to the [American Pet Products Association](http://www.americanpetproducts.org/press_industrytrends.asp) the **estimated number for 2011 is $50.84 billion**.

[image: Statistics 1]

**Breakdown of estimated 2011 Sales within the U.S. Market:**

[image: Statistics 2]

**Actual Sales within the U.S. Market in 2010:**

[image: Statistics 3]

For more statistics click the link above.

(I don't know if *farm animals* are included in these numbers)

---

From [Businessweek - The Pet Economy](http://www.businessweek.com/magazine/content/07_32/b4045001.htm) (2007):

> "*People are no longer satisfied to reward their pet in pet terms*,"
>   argues Bob Vetere, president of the American Pet Products
>   Manufacturers Assn. (APPMA). "*They want to reward their pet in human
>   terms*."
>
> That means hotels instead of kennels, braces to fix crooked
>   teeth, and frilly canine ball gowns.
>
> **Pet owners are becoming
>   increasingly demanding consumers who won't put up with substandard
>   products, unstimulating environments, or shoddy service for their
>   animals**. But the escalating volume and cost of services, especially in
>   the realm of animal medicine, raises ethical issues about how far all
>   this loving should go.

---

### **Comparison with Germany:**

In the **United States** (from the [2011-2012 APPA National Pet Owners Survey](http://www.americanpetproducts.org/pubs_survey.asp)):

> - Cats: 86.4 millions
> - Dogs: 78.2 millions
> - Birds: 16.2 millions

In **Germany** (from [Industrieverband Heimtierbedarf - Heimtiermarkt 2010](http://www.ivh-online.de/de/home/der-verband/daten-fakten.html))

> - Cats: 8.2 millions
> - Dogs: 5.3 millions
> - Birds: 3.5 millions

with a **total sales volume of 3.7 billion Euros for 2010** (at the current exchange rate that would be **$4.95 billion**).

Comment: so roughly the same expidenture per pet owner (and pet) in both countries, given that the US has roughly 10 times the population of Germany if I recall correctly.

Comment: @jwenting 10 times? ;) its 311:80 ratio in population

Comment: Always thought it was between 30 and 50 million, hence the 1/10 ratio :)

Comment: It was about 60 millions when it was West-Germany, before the reunion, 1990.